# Media queries aren't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use media queries for the first time. I have the following meta tag in my head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is my HTML.

```
<p id="quote-box">"Quote."</p>
```

I have the following code in my CSS.

```
#quote-box {
    background: darkred;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: 21%;
}

@media (min-width:900px){

    #quote-box {
        background: darkred;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        height: 10%;
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure what to try/do. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width:900px) {` or `@media all and (min-width:900px){`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the media query correctly, your css is just slightly off.

When viewing the snippet, view in fullscreen and change the window width.

So the `#quote-box` will be blue and small when `window.width > 900px`, otherwise will be red, but big.

```css
#quote-box {
    background: darkred;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: 200px;
}

@media all and (min-width:900px){
    #quote-box {
        background: blue;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        height: 100px;
    }   
}
```

```html
<p id="quote-box">"Quote."</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to specify your media type. see:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking about...but with media queries, I believe you only need to add the attributes that will be changing/different from the original. So with your example above the only thing that is changing from the original is the height attribute.
Maybe checkout these for additional help:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries